# How to mimic string/thread art with vectors in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, typography, patterns, illustrator-scripting

I'm designing a wall mural for an office and have to do an illustrator mock up of a string art wall similar to this:

[image]

Does anyone know how to achieve a similar effect? I tried searching all kinds of keywords for tutorials and haven't been able to find anything. Can someone explain how to do this or point me in the direction of a tutorial or script that would help?

Comment: You do it exactly the same way as you do it with the strings in firsplace.

Comment: That particular piece *appears* to be hand drawn. Grab colored pens and a ruler??